# How can I read and write php 5.6 error log?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, php-5.6

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, Apache/2.4.41, PHP 5.6.40-57.

When I call

```
error_log ('Page is not writable for save called)', 3, "/var/log/apache2/php_error.log");
```

there is nothing in /var/log/apache2/php_error.log.
php_error.log file is exist, and it is 777.

When I open /var/log/apache2/error.log, this error log was added.

```
PHP Warning:  error_log(/var/log/apache2/error.log):
 failed to open stream: \xed\x97\x88\xea\xb0\x80 \xea\xb1\xb0\xeb\xb6\x80 in /var/www/html/moniwiki/wiki.php on line 1258, referer: https:/
/myhome.ddns.net:9443/moniwiki/wiki.php?015B
```

1. why php_error.log is empty?
2. how am I able to change these \xed.. character to normal character?
3. what is \xed... and is there any website to decode these characters?

Comment: You have 2 error handler? I think you can only have one and use `throw new ErrorException` to write your exception on whatever filename  is  `error_log` set on .. perhaps they conflicting each other?

Comment: I found \xed\x97\x88\xea\xb0\x80 \xea\xb1\xb0\xeb\xb6\x80 means 'permission denied".
I just need to call
error_log ('Page is not writable for save called)', 0);
then I can found it in /var/log/apache2/error.log